# Migrations with async DataSource Typeorm+Nestjs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I was wondering if someone knows how to generate and run migrations using an async DataSource from TypeORM on a NestJS environment.

What I mean with `async DataSource` is that the values of the database connection are fetched on the fly (from a secret manager provider).

There is a PR with this information [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8914) but, what is the best practice to merge this "concept" into NestJS?. Do I need to create two separate DataSource configurations?, one for nest and one for the migrations?.

My proyect run the `TypeOrmModule` like this (and works as expected when starting nest):

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        await configService.setDBCredentials();
        return {
          type: TRANSACTIONAL_DATABASE_TYPE,
          host: configService.transactionalDatabaseCredentials.DATABASE_HOST,
          port: configService.transactionalDatabaseCredentials.DATABASE_PORT,
          username: configService.transactionalDatabaseCredentials.DATABASE_USER,
          password: configService.transactionalDatabaseCredentials.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
          database: configService.transactionalDatabaseCredentials.DATABASES_NAME,
          entities: [Member]
        }
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
```

Answer (score 1):

The Github link to the issue has been updated [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8914), notably by DanielMaranhao.
Personally, I still use 2 datasources (one for migrations and one for Nest configuration)

In addition to the configuration you show, I created this file named "data-source.ts" in my src/database folder

```
// src/database/data-source.ts

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as dotenvExpand from 'dotenv-expand';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

dotenvExpand.expand(dotenv.config());

export default new DataSource({
  type: 'mysql',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: +process.env.DB_PORT,
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  migrations: ['dist/database/migrations/*.js'],
  extra: {
    charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  },
 });
```

To **generate** a migration :

```
yarn run typeorm migration:generate -d dist/database/data-source -p src/database/migrations/[aNameForYourMigration]
```

Don't forget to change *[aNameForYourMigration]* by what you want

To **run** your migrations :

```
yarn run typeorm migration:run -d dist/database/data-source
```

Comment: So Nest has this data already but you have to duplicate it into another file called DataSource for it to be picked up?

Answer (score 1):

With the issue referenced here closed, here's a method to leveraging the TypeORM config from NestJS with the typeorm cli for migrations.  You can save this as an `ormconfig.ts` file in your project root and then use the migration commands.  Adjust your AppModule import path as necessary for your app.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './src/app/app.module';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export default NestFactory.create(AppModule)
  .then((app) => app.get(DataSource))
  .then((dataSource) => Promise.all([dataSource, dataSource.destroy()]))
  .then(([dataSource]) => dataSource);
```

Comment: How would this go about? Cause setting the path in package.json throws an error. `"typeorm:run": "npm run typeorm migration:run -- -d ./ormconfig.ts"`

Comment: This helps to keep the config DRY. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @seju - here's what I have in my package.json for run scripts:

`"migration:run": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:run --dataSource ormconfig.ts",`

Comment: @MattZuba do you have a sample repository by any chance?